# ASP.NET - Accessing a Repeater nested in a GridView column?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, repeater

I have a blank Repeater nested inside a column in a GridView and want to use a button in the GridView to populate the Repeater on demand via code behind. I am having difficulties referencing the repeater inside my button's onCommand sub.

Here is the relevant markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Submission" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" />
            <Columns>
                ..........
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="AdminEditSubmission" runat="server" ImageUrl="edit_15.png"
                            alt="" OnCommand="loadDetails" CommandArgument="X" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                ..........
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="RptSubmissionDetail" runat="server">
                                </asp:Repeater>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

For the sake of this small example, I will simply try to update the repeater's header with "Hello world". However, when it gets to the last line, I get the dreaded "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
    Sub loadDetails(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
        Dim rpt As Repeater = CType(Page.FindControl("RptsSubmissionDetail"), Repeater)
        Dim tmpHdr As TemplateBuilder = New TemplateBuilder
        tmpHdr.AppendLiteralString("Hello World")
        rpt.HeaderTemplate = tmpHdr
    End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me how to reference this repeater from my ImageButton click sub? I have tried several, with **Page.FindControl("RptsSubmissionDetail")** only being my latest attempt.

Comment: This can help maybe: http://forums.asp.net/t/998368.aspx/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GridView's RowCommand you need to use `FindControl` on the `GridViewRow`:

```
Sub Submission_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "loadDetails" Then
      ' Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      ' property to an Integer.
      Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)  
      ' Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
      ' by the user from the Rows collection.
      Dim row = Submission.Rows(index)  
      Dim repeater = DirectCast(row.FindControl("RptSubmissionDetail"), Repeater)
    End If
End Sub
```

From the ImageButton's click event it's nearly the same. Cast the `sender` argument to the `ImageButton` and it's `NamingContainer` property to the `GridViewRow`. Then use `FindControl` as shown above:

```
Sub ImageButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim img = DirectCast(sender, ImageButton)
    Dim row = DirectCast(img.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim repeater = DirectCast(row.FindControl("RptSubmissionDetail"), Repeater)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I appreciate your answer. I am about to give your method a try and will gladly accept it once I have it working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageButton Click event write the following code

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In Submission.Rows
Dim r As Repeater = DirectCast(row.FindControl("RptsSubmissionDetail"), Repeater)           
If r IsNot Nothing Then
          ' do your work
End If
Next
```

or if you want to find repearter in a particular row you can find it as

```
Dim r As Repeater = DirectCast(Submission.Rows[0].FindControl("RptsSubmissionDetail"), Repeater)  ' Give the right index            
If r IsNot Nothing Then
          ' do your work
End If
```